# Keep Picture Ratio in Word File

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I add a picture via VBA in the Left Header Cell of a Word document - works fine with the following code. Now I want to keep the ratio of the Picture but want to change the size and I don't know how to do it:

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Dim dd1 As Document: Set dd1 = ActiveDocument
Dim rng1 As Range, seC As Section, an(2) As Long
Dim rngO As Range, rngAN As Range
Dim strToPict As String
    
For Each rngO In dd1.StoryRanges

ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

If rngO.StoryType = wdEvenPagesHeaderStory Then
Set rng1 = rngO.Duplicate
For Each seC In rng1.Sections
    an(0) = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Height
    an(1) = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Width
    Set rngAN = seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Range.Duplicate
    seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=strToPict, _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rngAN

        With seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1)
         .Height = 50
         .LockAspectRatio = True
        
        End With
Next

Dim i As Long

ActiveDocument.Save
'Footer changing'
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(i)
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Name + "Text"
    End With
Next

End If

Next
 
End Sub
```

EDIT: I post the whole code of the Makro.

Answer (score 1):

«I add a picture via VBA in the Left Header Cell of a Word document». There is no such thing as a 'Left Header Cell' in a Word document. The only headers (and footers) Word has are Primary, First Page and Even Pages.

And, as Timothy said, you "really need to learn to use the tools at you fingertips". Moreover, having found LockAspectRatio, a simple web search - if that was really necessary - would show you how to use it.

In any event, since all it seems you're trying to do is to resize the inlineshape and repeat the primary page header, you could use something along the lines of:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, iShp As InlineShape, Sctn As Section, StrNm As String
With Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
  .Display
  StrNm = .Name
End With
With ActiveDocument
  If StrNm <> "" Then
    Set Rng = .Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
    Set iShp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=StrNm, _
      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=Rng)
    With iShp
      .LockAspectRatio = True
      .Height = 50
    End With
  End If
  Set Rng = .Sections.First.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME", PreserveFormatting:=False
  Rng.InsertAfter vbTab & "Text"
  For Each Sctn In .Sections
    Sctn.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = True
    Sctn.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = True
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I try the '.LockAspectRatio = True' but it does not scale the image in ratio. I can't find the problem. With "left header cell" I mean the left cell in a table within the header but it's not the problem here. So can you show me in my example where to put the "LockAspectRatio" in? Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh believe my I study your code ;) I insert the '.LockAspectRatio = True' right under my 'With seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1)' but it modify the ratio and don't keep it. So please be my mentor and show it in my specific example above :)

Comment: That's exactly the right place. However, if you've already messed up the aspect ratio, adding '.LockAspectRatio = True' now isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: ok. could be 'rngO.Duplicate' be the problem? Does it copy the ratio settings to?

Comment: All that 'Set rng1 = rngO.Duplicate' does is point a range object to a duplicate of rngO. It has no effect on the content of that range. Since you haven't posted enough of your code for anyone to work with, and haven't even told us what's in the even page header referenced by rngO.StoryType so we'd know what's going on, it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: I add the whole code above. I am new to that VBA stuff and can't find the error. Hope you can help me

Comment: "Oh believe my I study your code ;) I insert the '.LockAspectRatio = True' right under my 'With seC.Headers(1).Range.InlineShapes(1)' " - err, no you didn't. You added it *after* you changed the height.

Comment: See revised code. Most of your code (and mine) would not be needed if the template used for the document was properly designed. For example, if the template had a FILENAME field in the first Primary footer and all Primary footers had the 'LinkToPrevious' property set, none of your 'For i = 1 To' loop would be required. Much the same applies to the Primary headers and the inlineshape you're inserting - as I have already shown. Moreover, if you gave the row you're inserting the pic into a fixed height of the required size, you wouldn't even need any resizing code for the pic. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn to use the tools at you fingertips - IntelliSense, the Object Browser, and online help.

Scrolling through the options that IntelliSense gives you, or looking up `InlineShape` in the Object Browser, you would find `LockAspectRatio`. If you weren’t sure whether that was what you needed, pressing `F1` would take you to the [online help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshape.lockaspectratio).

Comment: I allready found the 'LockAspectRatio' but I get an error everytime. Where do I have to insert it?